# HTML/CSS custom font does not implement

Tags: html, css, fonts, html-lists

I'm trying to put together a very simple static page that uses a nice sans-serif opentype font stored in Amazon S3:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css">
                .block {
                    width: 800;
                    display: table;
                }
                .break {
                    height: 20px;
                }
                .top {
                    width:800px;
                    margin-top: 50px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .centralized {
                    width:800px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .unified {
                    width:800px;
                    text-align: left;
                }           
                .contact {
                    width: 800px;
                    text-align: center;
                }
            </style>
            <style type="text/css">
                @font-face {
                    font-family: "Neutral";
                    src: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/daniel.emmettschmidt.com/neutral.otf) format("opentype");
                }
                p.a { 
                    font-family: "Neutral", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    display: inline;
                    font-size:10px;
                }
                p.b { 
                    font-family: "Neutral", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    display: inline;
                    font-size:20px;
                }
                p.d { 
                    font-family: "Neutral", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    display: inline;
                    font-size:40px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class ="main_section">
                <div class ="block">
                    <div class="top">
                        <p class="d"><font color = "#305497"><b>TITLE</b></p></font>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact">
                        <p class="a">
                        CONTACT INFORMATION</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class = "block">
                    <div class="break"></div>
                    <div class = "unified">
                        <p class="b">
                            <b>
                                SUBHEADER:
                            </b>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="break"></div>
                    <div class ="centralized">
                        <p class = "a"><i>
                            EXTRA DETAILS
                        </i></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="break"></div>
                    <div class = "unified">
                        <p class ="a">
                            DESCRIPTION
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class ="break"></div>
                    <div class ="unified">
                        <p class = "a">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    LIST IS NOT SANS SERIFF
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    LIST IS NOT SANS SERIFF
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    LIST IS NOT SANS SERIFF
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
```

If you open that up in a browser, you'll see the font established in the header does not implement for the  list, can anyone help with this?

Comment: you also need other font formats for the web

Comment: You cannot place a `<ul>` tag inside a `<p>` tag... Check with your browsers development console. You will see that the browser tries to fix your broken html markup. The `<p>` gets closed again before the `<ul>` opens. That is why the style rules defining the font for the `<p>` tags is _not_ applied to the contents of the `<ul>`.

Comment: `<font>` is not a tag in HTML5, or in fact HTML 4.01 (it was deprecated some 20 years ago). Use CSS for text color. That said, open your browser's dev tools, and look at the console, and network tab, when you load your page. Does Amazing give you a 403, or 404, or 500, or Cross-Origin-Resource error, or anything else that blocks the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better if you put your `paragraph` `<p>` inside the list to make it work.

Try this structure and your problem was solved

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <p class = "a">
      LIST IS NOT SANS SERIFF
     </p>
  </li>
  <li>
     <p class = "a">
      LIST IS NOT SANS SERIFF
     </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance, its very helpful to see a working example, but does this mean that my font will only work with <p> tags and not with <li> or with <span> for that matter?

Comment: no, it will work with others it's just the structures of html is avoiding it. You can call your `<li> <span>` in a specific way to add the font. You can accept the answer for some future user.

Comment: I'll accept this since it comes closest, but you still aren't telling me exactly how to call the <li> in the "specific way to add the font". I'm already struggling with that and need help.

Comment: assuming that your `<li class="test">` the css will be `.test{font-family: "Neutral", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}` or you can call your `<li>` as general as `li{font-family: "Neutral", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}` you can post your code to jsfiddle so that I can help you

Answer (score 0):

Give that font to the < li > tags (in css) and remove that paragraphs

Comment: How? You aren't telling me, how?

Answer (score 0):

@import to load the Open Sans font from Google Fonts:
CSS first line is import the url of fonts.

```
@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
body {
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Similarly, you could link to the same asset as you would any other CSS filter, in the  of the HTML document rather than in the CSS. Using the same example from Google Fonts, this is what we would use:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Tried out the above code